# Caching WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

**EDIT: For each request, a new instance of controller is created. However, this is not true with Attribute classes. Once they are created, it is used for multiple requests. I hope it helps.**

I wrote my own WebAPI (using latest version of WebAPI and .net framework) caching action filter. I am aware about CacheCow & [this](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache). However, i wanted mine anyways.

However, there is some issue with my code because i don't get exepected output when i use it in my project on live server.  On local machine everything works fine.

I used below code in my blog RSS generator and i cache the data for each category. There are around 5 categories (food, tech, personal etc).

**Issue**: When i navigate to say api/GetTech it returns me the rss feed items from personal blog category. When i navigate to say api/GetPersonal , it returns me api/Food

I am not able to find the root cause but I think this is due to use of static method/variable. I have double checked that my `_cachekey` has unique value for each category of my blog.

Can someone point out any issues with this code esp when we have say 300 requests per minute ?

```
public class WebApiOutputCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        // Cache timespan
        private readonly int _timespan;

        // cache key
        private string _cachekey;

        // cache repository
        private static readonly MemoryCache _webApiCache = MemoryCache.Default;
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WebApiOutputCacheAttribute"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="timespan">The timespan in seconds.</param>
        public WebApiOutputCacheAttribute(int timespan)
        {
            _timespan = timespan;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext ac)
        {
            if (ac != null)
            {
                _cachekey = ac.Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.ToUpperInvariant();

                if (!_webApiCache.Contains(_cachekey)) return;

                var val = (string)_webApiCache.Get(_cachekey);

                if (val == null) return;

                ac.Response = ac.Request.CreateResponse();
                ac.Response.Content = new StringContent(val);
                var contenttype = (MediaTypeHeaderValue)_webApiCache.Get("response-ct") ?? new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/rss+xml");
                ac.Response.Content.Headers.ContentType = contenttype;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ac");
            }
        }




        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            if (_webApiCache.Contains(_cachekey)) return;
            var body = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                lock (WebApiCache)
                {
                    _wbApiCache.Add(_cachekey, body, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_timespan));
                    _webApiCache.Add("response-ct", actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.ContentType, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(_timespan));
                }

            }

        }



    }
```

---

Comment: "I thought that when a class has private variable & say we have 2 instance of class, each will have its own memory and own private variables." - yes this is true, I misled you. However, you are not dealing with 2 instances in this case. You are dealing with 1 instance being used by 2 or more different request threads.

Comment: Yup. And i think i don't need lock in the code as MemoryCache is thread safe. Is my understanding right ?

Comment: The `lock` when you add values to the cache is unnecessary and will only slow down requests that use the attribute, though probably not by very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same `WebApiOutputCacheAttribute` instance can be used to cache multiple *simultaneous* requests, so you should not store cache keys on the instance of the attribute. Instead, regenerate the cache key during each request / method override. The following attribute works to cache HTTP GET requests.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// based on strathweb implementation
// http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/output-caching-in-asp-net-web-api/
public class CacheHttpGetAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public ILogExceptions ExceptionLogger { get; set; }
    public IProvideCache CacheProvider { get; set; }

    private bool IsCacheable(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (Duration < 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Duration must be greater than zero.");

        // only cache for GET requests
        return request.Method == HttpMethod.Get;
    }

    private CacheControlHeaderValue SetClientCache()
    {
        var cachecontrol = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration),
            MustRevalidate = true,
        };
        return cachecontrol;
    }

    private static string GetServerCacheKey(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var acceptHeaders = request.Headers.Accept;
        var acceptHeader = acceptHeaders.Any() ? acceptHeaders.First().ToString() : "*/*";
        return string.Join(":", new[]
        {
            request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri,
            acceptHeader,
        });
    }

    private static string GetClientCacheKey(string serverCacheKey)
    {
        return string.Join(":", new[]
        {
            serverCacheKey,
            "response-content-type",
        });
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
        var request = actionContext.Request;
        if (!IsCacheable(request)) return;

        try
        {
            // do NOT store cache keys on this attribute because the same instance
            // can be reused for multiple requests
            var serverCacheKey = GetServerCacheKey(request);
            var clientCacheKey = GetClientCacheKey(serverCacheKey);

            if (CacheProvider.Contains(serverCacheKey))
            {
                var serverValue = CacheProvider.Get(serverCacheKey);
                var clientValue = CacheProvider.Get(clientCacheKey);
                if (serverValue == null) return;

                var contentType = clientValue != null
                    ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MediaTypeHeaderValue>(clientValue.ToString())
                    : new MediaTypeHeaderValue(serverCacheKey.Substring(serverCacheKey.LastIndexOf(':') + 1));

                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse();

                // do not try to create a string content if the value is binary
                actionContext.Response.Content = serverValue is byte[]
                    ? new ByteArrayContent((byte[])serverValue)
                    : new StringContent(serverValue.ToString());

                actionContext.Response.Content.Headers.ContentType = contentType;
                actionContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl = SetClientCache();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.Log(ex);
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = actionExecutedContext.Request;

            // do NOT store cache keys on this attribute because the same instance
            // can be reused for multiple requests
            var serverCacheKey = GetServerCacheKey(request);
            var clientCacheKey = GetClientCacheKey(serverCacheKey);
            if (!CacheProvider.Contains(serverCacheKey))
            {
                var contentType = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.ContentType;
                object serverValue;
                if (contentType.MediaType.StartsWith("image/"))
                    serverValue = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                else
                    serverValue = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var clientValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    new
                    {
                        contentType.MediaType,
                        contentType.CharSet,
                    });
                CacheProvider.Add(serverCacheKey, serverValue, new TimeSpan(0, 0, Duration));
                CacheProvider.Add(clientCacheKey, clientValue, new TimeSpan(0, 0, Duration));
            }

            if (IsCacheable(actionExecutedContext.Request))
                actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl = SetClientCache();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.Log(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Just replace the CacheProvider with your MemoryCache.Default. In fact, the code above uses the same by default during development, and uses azure cache when deployed to a live server.

Even though your code resets the `_cachekey` instance field during each request, these attributes are not like controllers where a new one is created for each request. Instead, the attribute instance can be repurposed to service multiple simultaneous requests. So don't use an instance field to store it, regenerate it based on the request each and every time you need it.

Comment: I dont get it. Say i have a cache item with key "TechCategory" then for next all requests, I will just check the MemoryCache object to see if i already have that data for the key "TechCategory". if it exists then return the output from cache. Whats is wrong with my code ?

Comment: What's wrong is that `_cacheKey` can be set by request A and then reused by request B, since one attribute instance can be used to service multiple simultaneous requests. Instead of setting this field and reusing it, regenerate it based on the request each and every time you need to use it.

Comment: I get your point but there is some confusion. So the  _cacheKey in my code is reset on per request ?

Comment: Here is the scenario that is happening: Request A thread goes into your method and sets _cacheKey. Then Request B thread goes into your method and gets _cacheKey, but it gets the value set by Request A. Try getting rid of the _cacheKey field and replace it with a static method that returns a new _cacheKey based on the current request. You only need to do this once per method, since each thread will get its own set of method variables. However all threads will share the same class instance variables like _cacheKey.

Comment: So what is wrong with it ? If request A (URL1) goes and creates an item in _webApiCache with _cacheKey = "techBlog"
Then request B for same URL1, goes and checks if there is a item in _webApiCache with _cacheKey = "techBlog" and ideally it should find it and just return the data from cache. Is this is now how it is supposed to work ?

in my code, ac.Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery returns different path for each blog category.

Comment: No the problem is that request A is setting _cacheKey to "techBlog" then request B is setting _cacheKey to "foodBlog" and then request A is getting _cacheKey and it gets "foodBlog" instead of "techBlog". Because it is a property of the class and not a variable within the method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64401/discussion-between-nexus-and-danludwig).